# PHP unpack float return unexpected answer

Tags: php, floating-point, binary, hex, unpack

I have some kind of binary data. I try to get the **Float** from that data. We already have the **Java version** for that program. So we already know what result should we get. When we try with the following `Php` code, the result is not the one that we expected.

Here is the code I used:

```
$readData = fread($stream, 4);
var_dump(unpack("f*", $readData)[1]); // -23944359936 wrong one
```

But if I try to get the **Hexadecimal** first from that binary and convert that Hexadecimal to **Float**, we get the expected result.

```
$readData = fread($stream, 4);
var_dump(self::hexTo32Float(bin2hex($readData))); // 0.22529149055481

public static function hexTo32Float($strHex) {
        $v = hexdec($strHex);
        $x = ($v & ((1 << 23) - 1)) + (1 << 23) * ($v >> 31 | 1);
        $exp = ($v >> 23 & 0xFF) - 127;
        return $x * pow(2, $exp - 23);
}
```

According to my understanding, they should generate the same result. Is there something do I miss to understand?

Comment: What is the input? With that input, what is the value of `$strHex`, `$v`, `$x`, `$exp`, and the final result? Is 0.22529149055481 the result you expect? What does “-23944359936 wrong one” mean?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, sorry for ambiguous. Yes, 0.22529149055481 is the result that we expected. -23944359936 is the one that we didn't expect. We already have the finalized Java version of the program that is fully tested. So we know what is the result that we should expect.

Comment: Not sure what this code does may be post java code too?